# Exception: No value given for one or more required parameters (Connected to Excel via C#)

Tags: c#

So I was trying to get the `foodChoice` value that the user selected but somehow when I put it into the sql statement, it just show "No value given for one or more required parameters however if I show it in the message box it does come out the selected value. Besides that if I hardcode the value for example "A" to replace the `foodChoice` that I selected, it does work. Anyone got any idea on how to fix this?

```
var dataSource = new List<foodType>();
dataSource.Add(new foodType() { foodName = "A", foodValue = "A" });
dataSource.Add(new foodType() { foodName = "B", foodValue = "B" });
dataSource.Add(new foodType() { foodName = "C", foodValue = "C" });
dataSource.Add(new foodType() { foodName = "ExtraA", foodValue = "extraA" });
dataSource.Add(new foodType() { foodName = "ExtraC", foodValue = "extraC" });

string connectString = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties =\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;\"";
OleDbConnection xlConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectString);
xlConnection.Open();
xlCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", xlConnection);
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(xlCommand);

dtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
da.Fill(dtSet);

lb_Initial.DisplayMember = "name";
lb_Initial.ValueMember = "name";
lb_Initial.DataSource = dtSet.Tables[0];
xlConnection.Close();

this.cB_food.DataSource = dataSource;
this.cB_food.DisplayMember = "foodName";
this.cB_food.ValueMember = "foodValue";

private void btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand xlCommand;
 string connectString1 = "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Book1.xlsx;Extended Properties =\"Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;\"";

 string foodChoice = cB_food.SelectedValue.ToString();
 string nameChoice = lb_Initial.SelectedValue.ToString();
 OleDbConnection xlConnection1 = new OleDbConnection(connectString1);
            xlConnection1.Open();
 xlCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET '"+foodChoice+"' = 1  WHERE name = '"+nameChoice+"' ", xlConnection1); //this is where the mistake is probably at

 xlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();//this is where the exception comes in
 MessageBox.Show(foodChoice);
 xlConnection1.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really certain a database will know what to do with a query like

```
UPDATE table SET 'yes' = halal
```

Are you sure you didn't mean to write

```
UPDATE table SET halal = 'yes'
```

In a where clause, equals can be either way round for sure, but I'm not certain all databases will have code to work out which side of an assignment is the column and which side is the value, they'll just expect it to be: SET column = 'value'

Comment: I have corrected my mistakes. It suppose to be = 1 but nonetheless, it still doesn't work. I have named the first row to 'A', 'B' , 'C' but somehow it's still result in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I somehow manage to solve it by removing the apostrophe in the line that I state it's most likely wrong. Although I solve it, I still do not understand how it does not work with the apostrophe. Anyone could explain to it?

The corrected code:

```
xlCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET "+foodChoice+" = 1  WHERE name = '"+nameChoice+"' ", xlConnection1);
```